# Need help understanding comment in Higher Topos Theory

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am having trouble understanding this part in *Lurie's Higher Topos Theory*. This can be found in  section 2.4.4.4 right after Lemma 2.4.4.1.

> **Lemma 2.4.4.1.** Let$ p : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ be an inner fibration of $\infty$-categories and
>   let $X, Y \in \mathcal{C}$. The induced map 
>   $$\phi : Hom^R_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) \rightarrow Hom^R_{\mathcal{C}}(p(X),p(Y))$$ is a
>   Kan fibration.
>
> [...]
>
> Suppose the coindtions of Lemma 2.4.4.1 are satisfied. Let us consider the problem of computing the fiber of $\phi$ over a vertex $\overline{e} : p(X) \rightarrow p(Y)$ of $Hom^R_{\mathcal{C}}(p(X), p(Y))$. Suppose that there is a $p$-Cartesian edge $e : X' \rightarrow Y$ lifting $\overline{e}$. By definition, we have a trivial fibration
>
> $$\psi : \mathcal{C}_{/e} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}_{/y} \times_{}\mathcal{D}_{/p(y)} \mathcal{D}_{/\overline{e}}.$$
>
> Consider the $2$-simplex $\sigma = s_1(\overline{e})$ regarded as a vertex  of $\mathcal{D}_{/\overline{e}}$. Passing to the fiber, we obtain a trivial fibration
>
> $$ F \rightarrow \phi^{-1}(\overline{e}),$$ where $F$ denotes the fiber of $\mathcal{C}_{/e} \rightarrow  \mathcal{D}_{/\overline{e}} \times_{\mathcal{D}_{/p(x)}} \mathcal{C}$ over the point $(\sigma, x)$.

I am not understanding exactly what he means by "taking fibers". I see that both $F$ and $\phi^{-1}(\overline{e})$ are fibers, but I don't know how he obtains the trivial fibration between them. I was thinking that both those fibers are defined by pullbacks which are actually homotopy pullbacks and maybe we can find a map of diagram in which all component are weak equivalences to have that those two fibers are weakly  equivalent. However I can't find those map and it would not show the that this map is a fibration.